# Should you set Random Seed Number during Hyperparameter Search in tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, hyperparameters

Given that algorithms like Neural Network are stochastic, should you set a random seed before running hyperparameter search? If you do not set random seed when searching for best hyperparams, how do you ensure that you can get the same results as the scenario with the best hyperparams when training the model?

Some say when running on GPU, we could not get reproducible results anyway, but how about run training on CPU?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML methodology.

Comment: Please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 2):

**"should you set a random seed before running hyperparameter search?":**
There are a lot of hyperparameter search strategies, including random search, grid search, a mixture of random and grid called "coarse to fine", bayesian methods etc. From a big picture point of view, these strategies explore the space of feasible possibilities broadly and some of them then try nearby "good" hyperparameter combinations that were found on an earlier pass of experimentation.

**"If you do not set random seed when searching for best hyperparams, how do you ensure that you can get the same results as the scenario with the best hyperparams when training the model?"**
You should keep track of different hyperparemater combinations that you explored (described in the strategy section above), even if they were initially selected randomly within a practical range set by the programmer. I would recommend thinking about randomness first as a strategy, then separately think about how to achieve reproducibility. Yes, if you apply the same hyperparams that you kept track of over and over you might get variable results, but in theory that should be much better on average than the worst set of hyperparams you found in the initial exploration of potential hyperparam combinations.

Comment: so you are saying that 100% model reproducibility is negligible since the best set of hyperparameters is found. Furthermore, it would not be far off from the one produced during the search and anyways, it will beat other sets of weak hyperparameters